# Is it possible to edit index.html on Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I've tried to make some changes on index.html on my page, for example I've added a section on the homepage with a video. But the change it only lasts a bit, after some time the page it's automatically restored as it was before.
The changes can only be made in the built in editor on Wordpress?

Comment: What index.html? Do you mean `index.php`? And what one? The one in your theme, the default theme? We need more information to be able to help you out.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check your file manager in your cPanel account or whatever web hosting account you are using. There may be a default page that they load automatically.

Comment: OP's question doesn't meet SO quality standards, and your answer is a shot in the dark at solving an unclear problem.